# Serve HTML file if it exists, otherwise redirect to index with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to write a rewrite rule to do the following: if any of the following files exist on the server as a static html file in a specific directory then I'd like `.htaccess` to serve that static file. Otherwise, I'd like the **id** (first number after the slash) to be passed as a query parameter to `www.gallery.com/index.php`

```
www.gallery.com/1-driving-to-the-beach.html   
www.gallery.com/2-swimming.html
```

Example: assume `www.gallery.com/2-swimming.html` doesn't exist as an html file on the server. I want **id=2** to be sent to `/index.php` where I can use

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html></html>
<?php
file_put_contents('2-swimming.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

Questions:

1. What is the rewrite rule my `.htaccess` file should contain?
2. How do I grab the **id** in `index.php` when the url is redirected by .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this rule to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENANE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENANE} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That sends the id portion of the request to `index.php` as the parameter **id**.

Comment: Will 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
work if I my id is more than 1 digit. For eg, id=20 or id=100. Will all the digits of the id be sent?

Comment: @user2726883 Yes, the `+` part of that grouping means "one or more" of the digits.

Comment: Thanks alot :) , what does [L] signify ? Usually I see [QSA] , [NC] etc.

Comment: @user2726883 It just means to stop rewriting in that iteration, L = "Last"